# smtplib: how to solve WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER error

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, version, smtplib

Starting from [this](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) this tutorial as reference point, I defined a simple function to send e-mail to my little SMPT server using a secure connection:

```
def send_mail_ssl(subject, text, receiver, sender, auth={}):
  body = _BODY_PATTERN.format(sender=sender,
                              receiver=receiver,
                              subject=subject,
                              text=text)
  # Create a secure SSL context
  context = _ssl.create_default_context()
  with _smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mydomain.com', 465, context=context) as server:
    server.set_debuglevel(2)
    if auth:
      username = auth.get('username', '')
      password = auth.get('password', '')
      server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, body)
```

However, each time I call that function, the following exception is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
[...]
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)
```

What's the meaning of this error and how could I solve it?

**Additional information:**

I have written a similar interface which relies on STARTTLS and seems to work correctly:

```
def send_mail_tls(subject, text, receiver, sender, auth={}):
  body = _BODY_PATTERN.format(sender=sender,
                              receiver=receiver,
                              subject=subject,
                              text=text)
  # Create a secure SSL context
  context = _ssl.create_default_context()
  # Try to log in to server and send email
  try:
    server = _smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mydomain.com', 587)
    server.set_debuglevel(2)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)  # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    if auth:
      username = auth.get('username', '')
      password = auth.get('password', '')
      server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, receiver, body)
  except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
  finally:
    server.quit()
```

Maybe the source of the issue in question is the current Postfix configuration?

Comment: Your SSL client and server don't find a common TLS protocol version which either means that they are misconfigured or one has a way too old TLS stack. It might also be a firewall in between fiddling with the connection. Hard to tell what is exactly the case without being able to check the exact server.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, how should I check SSL policies with regard to the utilization of the various TLS protocol?
Anyway, I have defined a similar function which relies on STARTTLS, port 587 and all seems to work fine in that case. Maybe, should I also check the Postfix configuration?

Comment: `WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER` happens also often if the other side does not speak TLS at all when expected. Thus, if you have configured port 465 wrongly (like the same as port 587, i.e. smtp+starttls instead of smtps) then this error can happen too. Thus, check the postfix configuration.